Playwright API Request fails with error: "Parse Error: Invalid header value char" for the GET request
I have a simple test using Playwright. It is to send a GET request with Authorization header using the Bearer token.
Below is a snippet of the code:
    const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${encodeURIComponent(token)}`, 'Accept': 'application/json', 
    }

    console.log('Headers being sent:', headers);

    const response = await request.get(`<someAPIURL>`, { headers: headers });
    console.log(response);
    // Validate the status code
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);

I see a failure and the error is as below:
Parse Error: Invalid header value char
I do not understand what could be possibly wrong here - I understand that there might be some additional spaces in the headers, but I do not see any such values. The headers are clean.
(The same API works with Postman)
I have used encodeURIComponent(token) to make sure the special chars are handled.
I have also tried replacing any newline characters by using .replace(/\\r?\\n|\\r/g, '')

Please share a [mcve].
